# Error System Drawing Common Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.drawing

I Install System.Drawing.Common version 4.5.0-preview2-26406-04 with Manage NuGet Package 
and after publish in my server
When I run project, I get this error

```
Error:
    An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (General.deps.json) was not found:
        package: 'System.Drawing.Common', version: '4.5.0-preview2-26406-04'
        path: 'runtimes/unix/lib/netcoreapp2.0/System.Drawing.Common.dll'
```

What can I do ?

Comment: As part of the [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/) it won't run on another platform.  Take a look at [.NET Core Image Processing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/) for alternatives.

Comment: System.Drawing.Common works perfectly fine on Linux and macOS. You just need to make sure you install its native dependency, libgdiplus. On Ubuntu/Debian, you can run `apt-get install -y libgdiplus`; on macOS you would run `brew install mono-libgdiplus`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload the runtime folder generated from the publish. It contains all the required platform specific references.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above by @Mark G, `System.Drawing.Common` won't run on Linux so you need to install the Linux compatible package. 
Use this, `dotnet add package runtime.linux-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing --version 1.0.0-beta009` in the terminal to install the Linux compatible `System.Drawing`.
Afterwards, publish your application again and everything should be fine now.